# Shaft Encoder Accuracy

Tags: sensors, interrupt, rotary-encoder

So, first of all I just want to point out this code is from: [Reading Rotary Encoders](http://playground.arduino.cc/Main/RotaryEncoders) and is not mine.

I have a magnetic shaft encoder mounted on a regular DC motor, my problem is that I cannot receive the exact angle of the motor. The encoder outputs `+1` each 90 degrees (I then multiply by 90). And is there any relationship between `valx`, `valy`, `valz` and the angle?

```c
#define encoder0PinA 2
#define encoder0PinB 3
int rounds= 0;
volatile unsigned int encoder0Pos = 0;
unsigned int tmp_Pos = 1;
unsigned int valx;
unsigned int valy;
unsigned int valz;

boolean A_set;
boolean B_set;

int enA = 9;
int in1 = 10;
int in2 = 11;

void setup() {

  pinMode(encoder0PinA, INPUT); 
  pinMode(encoder0PinB, INPUT); 
  // encoder pin on interrupt 0 (pin 2)
  attachInterrupt(0, doEncoderA, CHANGE);

  // encoder pin on interrupt 1 (pin 3)
  attachInterrupt(1, doEncoderB, CHANGE);
  Serial.begin( 9600 );

  pinMode(enA, OUTPUT);

  pinMode(in1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(in2, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(in1, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(in2, LOW); 
  analogWrite(enA, 225);
  Serial.begin (9600);
}


void loop(){ 
//Check each second for change in position

  if (tmp_Pos != encoder0Pos) {
    Serial.print("Index:"); Serial.print(encoder0Pos * 90,DEC);
    Serial.println();
    Serial.print("valx:");Serial.print(valx,DEC);
    Serial.println();
    Serial.print("valy:");Serial.print(valy,DEC);
    Serial.println();
    Serial.print("valz:");Serial.print(valz,DEC);
    Serial.println();
    tmp_Pos = encoder0Pos;
  }
}


// Interrupt on A changing state
void doEncoderA(){

  // Low to High transition?
  if (digitalRead(encoder0PinA) == HIGH) { 
    A_set = true;
    if (!B_set) {
      encoder0Pos = encoder0Pos + 1;
      valx=analogRead(0);
      valy=analogRead(1);
      valz=analogRead(2);
    }        
  }

  // High-to-low transition?
  if (digitalRead(encoder0PinA) == LOW) {
    A_set = false;
  }    
}

// Interrupt on B changing state
void doEncoderB(){

  // Low-to-high transition?
  if (digitalRead(encoder0PinB) == HIGH) {   
    B_set = true;
    if (!A_set) {
      encoder0Pos = encoder0Pos - 1;
    }
  }

  // High-to-low transition?
  if (digitalRead(encoder0PinB) == LOW) {
    B_set = false;
  }
}
```

Comment: Provide a link to the rotary encoder used.

Comment: Wiring?  Picture?

Comment: If the motor speed is fairly steady with only gradual speed up slowdown, you may be able to model it with a *software locked loop* running faster and adjusted to match the timing of the four pulses you do get.  You can then use that to interpolate the *likely* position at any point in time to a higher resolution.

Answer (score 2):

If the encoder only gives +1 pulse per 90 degrees, you aren't going to get better than 90 degree accuracy out of it.

In the example code at the link, the val{x,y,z} are measured analog variables of some other thing that are sampled at each encoder lcoation:

> My project is a data loger where three analogue inputs are sampled
>   each time a rotary encoder pulse steps clockwise. On an Arduino, time
>   is of the essence to get this data sampled and saved somewhere (I have
>   not included the 'saving somewhere' part of this project yet.) In
>   order to save some processor cycles, I have slightly redesigned the
>   interrupt system to maintain a pair of boolean states outside of the
>   interrupt loop.

These are not directly related to the positioning of the encoder, and there is no reason to think they provide angle information.